# Java ProcessBuilder.start(Tomcat7.exe) starts the process but it hangs help please?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I am starting an existing Tomcat 7 installation programmatically from within a Java class.
Pseudocode.. boring details like full path to my tomcat excluded

```
startTomcat(){
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("Tomcat7.exe");
  pb.start();
}
```

Then another method 
    stopTomcat() {
      pb.destroy()
    }

When startTomcat() is called, I can see Tomcat7 show up in the windows process list, but it's only using 24k memory and nothing goes into the logs... so when stop is called it dies.. and basically nothing has happened.  If I take the call to stopTomcat() out, as soon as my object is finished running, the Tomcat server starts in earnest.  The resources go up to 500k+ and the log starts filling up with activity from applications that live within that installation.

What can I do to stop this hanging behavior?  I have a wait set up .. that waits 2 minutes to give Tomcat time to initialize and my war time to do what I am wanting it to do .. then I just want to shut it down.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Just a tip: By making it immediately clear what you are asking (look at other questions for guidance), you will usually get more and better answers. Your question reads more like a story ;-)

Comment: Start it inna different thread. Problem solved.

Comment: I went the thread route.. before I chased the embedded rabbit down a hole two days ago.. I'll make the thread mods and when it doesn't work I'll come back and ask again.

Comment: putting it in a different thread has zero impact.  The tomcat server starts but doesn't "do" anything until my code exits.. which is too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this was the problem, or if it's just a work around.. but I got it to work and wanted to post how.

The Tomcat7 installation is registered as a service .. so, instead of running the Tomcat7.exe from my code.. I simply make a dos call to start the service:  net start Tomcat7, net stop Tomcat7

Thanks to those who responded..

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly address your final question, but with respect to getting embedded Tomcat to correctly scan the entire classpath, try something along the lines of:

```
Path baseDir = Files.createTempDirectory("integration-test").toAbsolutePath();

tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setBaseDir(baseDir.toString());

tomcat.setHostname("localhost");
tomcat.setPort(0); // random free port

Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("/", baseDir.toString());

StandardJarScanner jarScanner = (StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner();
jarScanner.setScanAllDirectories(true);

tomcat.start();

endpoint = URI.create("http://localhost:" + tomcat.getConnector().getLocalPort());
```

The key is `jarScanner.setScanAllDirectories(true)`, which causes the scanner to look in all directories on the classpath *that themselves contain a `META-INF` directory*.

Comment: First.. THANK YOU, for taking the time to submit an answer!!  This is why I worded the question the way I did initially, but the stack gods didn't "get" it and changed it. SO I totally started over. NO, I don't want to embed a server for reasons I explained in my original question but deleted. I want to launch an EXISTING tomcat from inside my code. The instance starts.. it just doesn't do anything until my code exits.. I just added a thread .. it's still not working.